# Python PermissionError being used by another process:

Tags: python, watchdog

I'm trying to make the 2. version of the move file starting at 2:53, the version 1 start at 1:18 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbW6FRbaSl0

I have this code, and if I CTRL+lmouse click/drag a file into "test1" folder, it rename it and transfer it to the "test2" folder.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
#pip install watchdog

import os
import time


class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    i = 1

    def on_modified(self, event):
        new_name = "new_file_" + str(self.i) + ".txt"
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            file_exists = os.path.isfile(folder_destination + "/" + new_name)
            while file_exists:
                self.i += 1
                new_name = "new_file_" + str(self.i) + ".txt"
                file_exists = os.path.isfile(folder_destination + "/" + new_name)

            src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
            new_destination = folder_destination + "/" + new_name
            os.rename(src, new_destination)


folder_to_track = '/Users/TH/Desktop/test1'
folder_destination = '/Users/TH/Desktop/test2'
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

My problem is if i'm trying to drag another (file 2) into the "Test1" folder, then i get this error... (Then i need to restart pc and can then do it with the first file, and the second file will start the error again.)

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
> because it is being used by another process:
> '/Users/TH/Desktop/test1/skole.txt' ->
> '/Users/TH/Desktop/test2/new_file_2.txt'

Can someone help/guide me.

Comment: No one that can help ?